# Troubles with AdMob Android - ErrorCode: 0

Tags: android, admob

I'm having issues with AdMob on an Android app.
I do all steps in Android developer guide, but when I click on the activity no ad is shown.
That's the code I implemented:

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  

....
//before activties...
<!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

In my Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mat123.Home_activity" >


 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In my Home_Activity.java

```
//imported packages
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("***My devide id***").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My full logcat filtered on "ads":

```
05-17 12:00:18.758    6239-7566/com.example.mat123 D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-341320604.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
    05-17 12:00:18.798    6239-6239/com.example.mat123 I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
    05-17 12:00:18.818    6239-6239/com.example.mat123 I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
    05-17 12:00:18.868    6239-7566/com.example.mat123 D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads-341320604.jar' (success) ---
    05-17 12:00:18.868    6239-7566/com.example.mat123 D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.mat123/cache/ads-341320604.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 114ms
    05-17 12:00:29.538    6239-7584/com.example.mat123 W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
    05-17 12:00:29.548    6239-6239/com.example.mat123 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.h.<init>
    05-17 12:00:29.658    6239-6239/com.example.mat123 W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

In my build.grandle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

I have searched for a long time, but i can't get a solution.
I changed compile setting in build.grandle to other versione (like 7.3.0 or on 6.0.0)..
I have deleted Google Repository and reinstalled.
I changed app ads unit id.
I refreshed the project.
I made also another new project, but I get the same errors.
I'm testing my app on my real device (Note 3).

No other things to say, i don't know what is the problem.

PS : (I have implemented everything also on Eclipse ( except the compile in build.granle->I imported google play services libraries)) but I get the same errors.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Did you just create your app's ad id? It may not fill right away. Also, make sure you use the latest GPS `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0`.

Comment: Thabks for answering.

Comment: I had adaway installed by default with my custom rom.

Comment: So either delete or post your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was about adaway installed on my phone with a custom rom.
So, no error in the code.

Thansk for helping, and hope this can be helpful for someone in future.

Answer (score 2):

Your Application id was deleted or blocked by admob. You can change your package name and then run it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your publisher id is blocked. See discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/VUjq-cnmKlQ

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem was that i had adaway installed on my phone by default by my custom rom.thanks.